# Require stack: \\ Error I've never heard of

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

> throw err;
> ^
> Error: Cannot find module  './C:\Users\domri\OneDrive\Desktop\Repositories\Discord Bot\commands\test/ping.js'

The error is found somewhere in here

```js
const isDirectory = source => fs.lstatSync(source).isDirectory();
const getDirectories = source => fs.readdirSync(source).map(name => join(source, name)).filter(isDirectory);



getDirectories(__dirname + '/commands').forEach(category => {
  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(category).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./${category}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    if (command.aliases) {
      for (const alias of command.aliases) {
        client.aliases.set(alias, command.name);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Specific line numbers and labelled lines where the error stack says. Also perhaps include what you are trying to achieve in your question, that would help if someone had a different solution to you. (instead of fixing unfix-able code)

Comment: Could it be a silly mistake like you deleted something from your OneDrive? Because I see the path includes that

Answer (score 0):

Send the console err your got please, or check if you have installed the npm used, try `npm i` or `npm ci` and because it is `discord.js` try this `npm i discord.js` first before you do `npm i` or `npm ci`!